# Thread-local arrays in cython's prange without huge memory allocation

Tags: multithreading, numpy, memory-management, cython, gil

I have some independent computations I would like to do in parallel using Cython.

Right now I'm using this approach:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as cnp
from cython.parallel import prange

[...]

cdef cnp.ndarray[cnp.float64_t, ndim=2] temporary_variable = \
    np.zeros((INPUT_SIZE, RESULT_SIZE), np.float64)
cdef cnp.ndarray[cnp.float64_t, ndim=2] result = \
    np.zeros((INPUT_SIZE, RESULT_SIZE), np.float64)

for i in prange(INPUT_SIZE, nogil=True):
    for j in range(RESULT_SIZE):
        [...]
        temporary_variable[i, j] = some_very_heavy_mathematics(my_input_array)
        result[i, j] = some_more_maths(temporary_variable[i, j])
```

This methodology works but my problem comes from the fact that I in fact need several `temporary_variable`s. This results in **huge** memory usage when `INPUT_SIZE` grows. But I believe what is really needed is a temporary variable in each thread instead.

Am I facing a limitation of Cython's prange and do I need to learn proper C or am I doing/understanding something terribly wrong?

**EDIT**: The functions I was looking for were `openmp.omp_get_max_threads()` and `openmp.omp_get_thread_num()` to create a reasonably sized temporary array. I had to `cimport openmp` first.

Comment: Cython generally assigns thread locals correctly (if you just make it a scalar rather than array). Failing take, see if you can put the loop body in a separate function with its own local variables

Comment: @DavidW Thanks for your help. I should probably split my code into smaller functions because I need arrays. I'm struggling to figure out how to do so unfortunately.

Comment: I'll try to write a note complete answer in the next few days but my suggestion was that if the two lines shown (`temp_var = ...` and `some_more_maths(temp_var)`) are contained in a function then the variable is local to the function (so definitely thread local)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is something that Cython tries to detect, and actually gets right most of the time. If we take a more complete example code:

```
import numpy as np
from cython.parallel import prange

cdef double f1(double[:,:] x, int i, int j) nogil:
    return 2*x[i,j]

cdef double f2(double y) nogil:
    return y+10

def example_function(double[:,:] arr_in):
    cdef double[:,:] result = np.zeros(arr_in.shape)
    cdef double temporary_variable
    cdef int i,j
    for i in prange(arr_in.shape[0], nogil=True):
        for j in range(arr_in.shape[1]):
            temporary_variable = f1(arr_in,i,j)
            result[i,j] = f2(temporary_variable)
    return result
```

(this is basically the same as yours, but compilable). This compiles to the C code:

```
#pragma omp for firstprivate(__pyx_v_i) lastprivate(__pyx_v_i) lastprivate(__pyx_v_j) lastprivate(__pyx_v_temporary_variable)
                #endif /* _OPENMP */
                for (__pyx_t_8 = 0; __pyx_t_8 < __pyx_t_9; __pyx_t_8++){
```

You can see that `temporary_variable` is set to be thread-local. If Cython does not detect this correctly (I find it's often too keen to make variables a reduction) then my suggestion is to encapsulate (some of) the contents of the loop in a function:

```
cdef double loop_contents(double[:,:] arr_in, int i, int j) nogil:
    cdef double temporary_variable
    temporary_variable = f1(arr_in,i,j)
    return f2(temporary_variable)
```

Doing so forces `temporary_variable` to be local to the function (and hence to the thread)

---

With respect to creating a thread-local array: I'm not 100% clear exactly what you want to do but I'll try to take a guess...

1. I don't believe it's possible to create a thread-local memoryview.
2. You could create a thread-local C array with `malloc` and `free` but unless you have a *good* understanding of C then I would not recommend it.
3. The easiest way is to allocate a 2D array where you have one column for each thread. The array is shared, but since each thread only touches its own column that doesn't matter. A simple example:

   ```
   cdef double[:] f1(double[:,:] x, int i) nogil:
       return x[i,:]

   def example_function(double[:,:] arr_in):
       cdef double[:,:] temporary_variable = np.zeros((arr_in.shape[1],openmp.omp_get_max_threads()))
       cdef int i
       for i in prange(arr_in.shape[0],nogil=True):
           temporary_variable[:,openmp.omp_get_thread_num()] = f1(arr_in,i)
   ```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer. However, I still don't understand how to make `temporary_variable` an thread-local **array** (see the edit on my post). Maybe this is not something that can be done in cython and I need to refactor my code in order to avoid needing thread-local arrays.

Comment: Thanks again. #3 is what I was already doing; the problem is that it requires a huge amount of RAM for large inputs. I guess #2 is what I need to do, but I need to improve my C skills first. Right now, I just gave up on parallelism for this specific case and well, it gives me an excuse to hang out on SO while waiting for my results. :o)

Comment: It isn't the same as what you show in the question. You create an array that's input_size x result_size. I create an array that's input_size x number_of_threads. number_of_threads is typically reasonably small (4 or 8?).

Comment: Oh sorry I missed that. I think that is exactly what I was looking for. I'll try it ASAP. Thank you very much.

Comment: Is there any reason to return something? I adapted the `cdef` to be of `void` return type, and passed the `temporary_variable` to it, so `cython -a` ends up all white, and it seems to work.

Comment: Your way should work fine - you don't have to return it.